# "you must set CPPTRAJHOME" while installing pytraj

Tags: python

while installing pytraj on my ubuntu I got this error. what should I do?

```
Collecting pytraj
  Using cached pytraj-2.0.5.tar.gz (20.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pjw3hpsa/pytraj/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pjw3hpsa/pytraj/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-pjw3hpsa/pytraj/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-pjw3hpsa/pytraj/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    sys.argv ['/tmp/pip-install-pjw3hpsa/pytraj/setup.py', 'egg_info', '--egg-base', '/tmp/pip-install-pjw3hpsa/pytraj/pip-egg-info']
    Original compiler envs
    CXX =
    CC =
    COMPILER =
    use_pip = True, cpptraj_home =
    Detected use of pip; you must set CPPTRAJHOME if there is no cpptraj in the current folder
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```